# Unreadable .dbf file

Tags: encryption, visual-studio-2013, foxpro, dbf

I am trying to open a .dbf file. The file is from an application directory. I would just like to access the raw data, but I am having some difficulty.

I am not looking for a how to, but would appreciate someone pointing me to a where to get to my solution. I do not know if this file is encrypted, or if it is from foxpro, or if I am simply not opening the file with the correct application. I feel like this would have been created from something old as far as software.

Included is an image of what the data looks like when I open the file. This is in Visual Studio. I have tried it in other IDEs as well as just plain old excel.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That looks like an unencrypted DBF created by either FoxBase or FoxPro (pre-Visual FoxPro) or dBase III Plus or dBase IV. What happens when you try to open it in Excel?

Comment: I've used a program like DBF viewer to attempt to open the files and I get the same data as Visual Studio. I think that would eliminate dBase III and dBase IV. I will see what I can do about getting FoxBase or FoxPro running.

Comment: Just download the Visual FoxPro OLEDB driver from Microsoft and see if you can connect to it as a standalone DBF from Visual Studio.

Comment: Well I setup the data connection in VS and still got unreadable data. My search continues. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The reason I said it was an older file is the "03" in the first byte. What you're seeing in Excel sure doesn't look like the same file. It has a different list of fields.

Comment: Tamar - I know it looks different. It has been a slightly frustrating beginning of a project. Here is the file open in three programs at the same time. Far left is Visual Studio, middle is Excel, right is Sublime 3. http://i.imgur.com/WoKKG1r.png

Comment: The VS image you just posted is different than the original one, so I'd say not the same table. (And they show different names.) If this is, in fact, encrypted, unfortunately, there are many different ways that could have been done. One pretty common in the last few years is http://www.sweetpotatosoftware.com/spsblog/2009/08/09/MajorVFPEncryptionUpdate.aspx. There also used to be a product called Cryptor that was fairly widely used. If what you're dealing with is encryption, I think you're going to want to use VFP to figure it out. VFP 9 is in MSDN.

Comment: Thanks for the response Tamar. You're right they are different files. I was just using one file to show that they appear differently in different editors. Thanks for your time and the pointers. I will continue my search.